# How to get time labels of silence periods in a file

Tags: software

Can someone advise a way how to automatically (with a script) get a list of time labels for periods of silence in an audio file?

Such a list can be obtained with the help of Audacity, but it seems there is no way to easily automate this task.

The list can be in any format. Moreover, it can even be a list with averaged (RMS?) for some time window sample values for the whole file, from which silence periods can be detected.

Comment: This sounds like it would be a better fit for [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Before posting here I checked that site and thought that this site is more appropriate: every music program has features related to silence (generating, removing...) so there are probably users of such programs who know how to do that. But if moderators decide to move this question, that's OK.

Comment: If you have any programming experience, and the audio is in an uncompressed format, it shouldn't be too difficult to programme a simple command-line tool yourself.

Comment: @Bob Seems like a good idea. I work with mp3 files, but I can convert them to raw audio with SoX.

Comment: "it seems there is no way to easily automate this task" Have you looked into Audacity's Macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few tools to do this but you might need to do a bit of work to install them.

- Aubio is a useful library https://aubio.org/manual/latest/cli.html#aubioquiet
- Sox can't but ffmpeg can - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37176322/2618015)
- Essentia is a heavy duty library but has some command line tools available https://essentia.upf.edu/extractors_out_of_box.html The extractor you would need is https://essentia.upf.edu/reference/std_StartStopSilence.html

Answer (score 0):

Try java sound api.

Check the following url for examples.

[Java Sound Resources: Examples: A - Z](http://jsresources.sourceforge.net/examples/examples_a_z.html)

Comment: The most appropriate section seems to be [this](http://jsresources.sourceforge.net/faq_audio.html#silence_supression), but it is of limited use besides introducing the term *noise gate*.